# I cannot run my Angular 7 PWA on localhost:8080

Tags: angular

I followed this commands when I created my Angular PWA:

```
ng new pwa-my-site
cd my-site
ng add @angular/pwa
```

After that I installed http server:

```
npm install -g http-server
ng build --prod
http-server -c-1 dist/pwa-my-site
```

But when I went to `http://localhot:8080` the page was empty, and show me this message:

> A network protocol violation has occurred and communication cannot be restored.

Comment: check your localhost spelling you have missed s in that typo.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a typo localhot:8080 instead of localhost:8080 (mit S)?

Your steps are correct and it should work correctly. I wrote a [tutorial to create a PWA with Angular from scratch](https://dev.to/paco_ita/create-progressive-web-apps-with-angular-workbox-pwa-builder-step-4-27d#angular). You can have a look and compare with your code.
The article also points to a working Angular PWA with caching strategies for static assets and GET HTTP requests.

Comment: Thanks! I opened the link and used web server for Chome and it is work

Comment: Glad it helped. Then you can accept the answer, even if it was an easy fix :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have Windows OS (otherwise, you may need a bit different params for netsat).
You can try the following command

> netstat -aon | findstr ":8080"

It should show a line like

> TCP   127.0.0.1:8080      <few more columns here, last one is PID aka "Process ID">

If output is empty, nothing is really listening on 8080. Otherwise, that means that your port binding is up and running, and the issue is one level higher (most likely, your browser security settings that blocks any localhost bindings, try another browser or bind to your Network card IP address instead of localhost).